# Is it possible to return a Map<Type, Pair(List<Type2>, List<Type3>)> using Room Database?

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, orm, android-room

I have the entitys `movie`, `person`, `movie_actor` (relation between movie and person for actors), `movie_director` (relation between movie and person).
I Want to get the list of movies with actors and directors. I now i can create the `MovieWthActorsAndDirectors` class and use:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM movie")
    @Transaction
    fun getMoviesWithActorsAndDirectors(): List<MovieWithActorsAndDirectors>
```

But i want to know if i can use something like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT * from movie " +
            "JOIN movie_actors ON movie_actors.id_movie = movie.id " +
            "JOIN person ON movie_actors.id_actor = person.id")
    fun getMoviesWithActors(): Map<Movie, List<Person>>

    @Query("SELECT * from movie " +
            "JOIN movie_director ON movie_director.id_movie = movie.id " +
            "JOIN person ON movie_director.id_director = person.id")
    fun getMoviesWithDirectors(): Map<Movie, List<Person>>
```

but that can return `Map<Movie, Pair(List<Person>, List<Person>)>`

Thanks.

I tryed to write the following:

```
    @Query("SELECT * from movie " +
            "JOIN movie_actors ON movie_actors.id_movie = movie.id " +
            "JOIN person ON movie_actors.id_actor = person.id " +
            "JOIN movie_director ON movie_director.id_movie = movie.id " +
            "JOIN person ON movie_director.id_director = person.id") 
    fun getMoviesWithActors(): Map<Movie, Pair(List<Person>, List<Person>)>
```

But didn't work.